# Obtener el porcentaje de 2 consultas con barra de progreso

Tags: php, mysqli

Como puedo obtener el porcentaje de 2 consultas en una sola, en este caso seria el de frags y deaths y añadirle una barra de progreso

Edit: frags aumentaria el porcentaje y el deaths lo bajaria

```html
            $n = 1+$desde;
            $query = $db->query('SELECT rankurl, ProfileImg, ProfileUrl, name, frags, rankname, deaths, headshots, cuchillo, captured, returned FROM '.$dbTable.' ORDER BY frags DESC LIMIT '.$desde.', '.$por_pagina.'') or die ("Error en la consulta: ".mysqli_error($db));
            while ($top = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
            {
                $avatar= str_replace("https://", "http://", $top["ProfileImg"]);
                ?>
                <tr>
                <td><?php echo "$n" ?></td>
                <td><a href=<?php echo $top["ProfileUrl"]?> target="_blank"> <img src=<?php echo "$avatar"?> width="35" height="35"/></a></td>
                <td><a><img src=<?php echo $top["rankurl"]?> width="22" height="22"/></a></td>
                <td><?php echo substr($top['name'], 0, 15) ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $top["rankname"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $top["frags"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $top["deaths"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $top["headshots"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $top["cuchillo"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $top["captured"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $top["returned"] ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php
            $n++;
            }
```

Comment: No se como explicarlo bien, el total me imagino que te refieres al limite no? seria que no pasara de 100% y en cuanto para calcular el porcentaje seria que al tener mayor frags que deaths el % sea mayor pero si tienes mas deaths que frags el porcentaje sea menor no se si me explico

Comment: Si eso mismo, que los deaths afecten en el porcentaje, pero digamos que tienes mayor deaths que frags, el porcentaje seria menor pero que este no llegue a 0 tan facilmente es decir tendria que tener una gran cantidad de deaths para poder llevar ese porcentaje a 0

Comment: Diria que frags es el total y deaths le resta

Comment: Para asegurarnos de lo que estas pensando. `frags` representa el _"total de veces jugadas"_ y `deaths` representa _"cuantas veces perdió"_, correcto?

Comment: Perdon se habia ido la luz :c, los frags son kills, se suman a matar a un jugador y deaths se suma cuando mueres.

Comment: Me podrian ayudar porfis

Comment: No podes calcular un porcentaje ya que no existe un "total" de referencia. Lo que podes calcular es un "ratio", [más info](https://udoe.es/como-se-calcula-la-tasa-de-muertes-por-muerte/)

Comment: pero seria como dices el frag representa el total solo que se va a estar actualizando constantemente ya que frags representa kills y deaths muerte que es lo que se hara mayormente

Comment: Es que no es un total, es la relación muestes/muerte (K/D ratio). Un ejemplo para sacar un % seria, jugó 10, perdió 2, ahi podes sacar el % de victorias y derrotas en base al total de veces que jugó

Comment: y no se podria hacer lo mismo osea hizo tanto frags en una partida y en esa misma murio tantas veces y de ahi sacar el % lo que seria tendria que hacerle un guardado ya que eso se muestra en un top

Comment: Si siempre se enfrente contra 1 sola persona, entonces si. Se puede pensar que cada `frags` es una victoria y cada `deaths` es una derrota

Comment: y como le podria agregar una barra de progreso a ese %?

Comment: Si lo vas a hacer así, entonces el total es la suma de ambos y ese sería el 100%. Las victorias serían el x% del total y para calcular ese x aplicas una [regla de tres simple](https://www.smartick.es/blog/matematicas/algebra/regla-de-3-simple/)

Answer (score 0):

Lo pude solucionar, graciasss :D

Edit: lo hice de esta forma, no se si sea la correcta.

```html
                $porcentaje = $top["frags"] ? (100.0 * ((float)$top["frags"]) / ((float)$top["frags"] + $top["deaths"])) : (0.0);
                $porcentaje = round($porcentaje, 0);
```

[image]